# Is there the equivalent of next in Pry?

Tags: ruby, pry

I don't see a way of just going to the next line when using pry as a debugger.  All I can find is to edit the method and move binding.pry to the next line.  Is there such a feature?

```
22:     def scan path
23:         @last_line_had_text, @files_read, @hands_read = nil, 0, 0
24:         Find.find(path){ |file_name|
=> 25:          binding.pry
26:             read_file(file_name) if file_name.include?(".txt")
27:         }
28:     end
```

Comment: see this answer for a more current solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16698615/1396904

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want (this and more) debugging features you'll need to use `pry_debug`: https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry_debug

Comment: Ah; I was hoping somebody would do this--it was a pain flopping bck and forth between ruby-debug and pry; cool.

Comment: @Dave Newton, you may also like the `ruby-debug_pry` project linked in my answer below

Answer (score 78):

Ctrl+D, you can jump to next break or exit

Answer (score 19):

Recommend to use `pry-byebug` if ruby version >2.0

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [ruby-debug_pry](https://github.com/AndrewO/ruby-debug-pry) which integrates pry as a `ruby-debug` command, enabling you to easily switch back and forth between the two.

A new project called [pry-nav](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav) is now the recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 10):

If using Using MRI 1.9.2+ then there is a new project, [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger), that is now the recommended replacement for pry-nav. It's by the same author as pry-nav and is faster.

Comment: for 2.0+ see Kit Ho's answer about using pry-byebug.