# Is there a pry debug setup that works with ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, pry

I'm using ruby 2.0.0-p195 on OSX. pry-debugger does not work (step/continue/next all appear to work like `continue`). Is there a pry debugging gem that works with ruby 2.0?

*update: `pry-debugger` and `pry-byebug` both appear to work with with ruby 2.0.0-p195 in a simple project. I have some other conflict that is causing both to fail when using `binding.pry` in tests...*

*update: `pry-byebug` is working for me with the latest ruby 2.0 release, 2.0.0-p247, with pry-byebug 1.1.1 & byebug 1.5.0*

Comment: So pry-byebug is not working in your tests? I am the mantainer, feel free to open an issue if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @deivid. I will open an issue if I can reproduce it in a simple project - I haven't been able to isolate what's causing the problem yet. I copied my Gemfile into a separate blank rails project & debugging works there in both pry-debugger and pry-byebug, so I'm currently at a loss.

Comment: Hope you get it sorted out, if I can help let me know!

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this issue, tee

Comment: +1 on the ruby 2.0 and pry-debugger interpreting every command as `continue`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`pry-byebug` 1.1.1+ works with ruby 2.0.0-p247. It's a fork of `pry-debugger` & works with ruby 2.0+ only.

```
gem 'pry-byebug'
```

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

*updated with version numbers*

Answer (score 0):

i found that removing pry-nav from my gemfile returned functionality to next. see also: [issue #9](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/9)